# turn off wifi during certain hours

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I want to restrict access of a laptop and allow it in certain hours only, with a password of course.
router is linksys WRT160N, but access restrictions doesn't work
firmware: v1.52.0

here's what I tried:

1. I checked timezone configuration, and corrected it.
2. I tried both allow\deny settings, neither are working

the problem seems to be in identifying the right time.
please help

Comment: [This should help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0Kjck9aMTk)

Comment: You can check the following link : http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=4041

Comment: thank you both, unfortunately I've already done all that, the problem is that access gets blocked at the wrong hours.